# How to find intensity of two object present in single image?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am working on python and using an open CV. I want to find the average intensities of two objects present in the image.
I think I can make contours and then find the intensities by considering each contour as a different object. But, I don't know how to do it.
My code up till now is

```
img = cv2.imread('F:\Multispectral Imaging\Readings\Reading to find intensity of two samples in one image\image0.bmp'
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
ret,thresh = cv.threshold(blur,50,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

What can I do after this tofind intensities of both white spots?
Below is the image.

[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Below Code. and I calculate the mean intensity of each object in the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)

#thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold( blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV , 201, 11)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold( gray, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )
thresh = cv2.erode( thresh, np.ones((5,5)))
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    mask = np.zeros_like(gray)
    cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0, 255, -1)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(gray,gray,mask=mask)
    idx = np.where( mask==255)
    print('mean:',np.mean(gray[idx]))
    print('max:',np.max(gray[idx]))

    cv2.imshow('object', res)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

> > mean = 193
> > max = 255

[image]

> > mean = 40
> > max=111

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is working perfectly